# no annotation found on method weaved by this annotation

Tags: spring, aspectj

i have an aspect that matches on methods with an annotation (this works otherwise this code wouldn't be called), now i use  org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationUtils to get the annotation, but that gives me a nullPointerException on the last line when i run the application in tomcat. it works fine in a unit-test.

```
before() : runWithContext() {
    MethodSignature methodSignature = (MethodSignature) thisJoinPoint
            .getSignature();
    Method targetMethod = methodSignature.getMethod();
    RunWithContext anno = AnnotationUtils.getAnnotation(targetMethod, RunWithContext.class);
    ContextInvocationUtils.replaceContext(anno.someValue());
}
```

tomcat as well as the unit-tests start a spring-container exactly the same in respect to where my weaved code is located (it the message-handler for a spring-integration outbound-channel-adapter)

my annotation looks like this

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
@Inherited
public @interface RunWithContext {

    String[] authorities() default {};

}
```

EDIT:

calling targetMethod.getAnnotation works, any hints what org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationUtils.getAnnotation(Method, Class) is for if it doesn't correctly get me the annotation in my case?

Comment: Is your annotation annotated with `@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)`?

Comment: it turns out simply calling targetMethod.getAnnotation works and AnnotationUtils.getAnnotation doesn't. that's solution enough for me now, but i just wonder what use AnnotationUtils.getAnnotation has then

Comment: It should be doing the exact same thing...At least you got a workaround.